# How to join multiple count(*) queries?

Tags: mysql, join, count, query-optimization

Is there a way to join multiple count(*) queries to a single one? I know that i don't need to prepare the last two queries two times but that's not what the question is about. I have no idea how to do this in a correct way.

```
$sth = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE topicid = ?');
$sth->execute( array( $this->_id ) );
$numPosts = $sth->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sth = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM topic_activity WHERE topicid = ?');
$sth->execute( array( $this->_id ) );
$numViews = $sth->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sth = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM topic_activity WHERE topicid = ? AND likes = 1');
$sth->execute( array( $this->_id ) );
$numLikes = $sth->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sth = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM topic_activity WHERE topicid = ? AND likes = -1');
$sth->execute( array( $this->_id ) );
$numDislikes = $sth->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answer of user3106988 'works', I would have gone for a more 'vertical' approach (and also store the id in a variable so you only need to pass it once, could be this doesn't work in your environment though, so could be you'll need to replace the @id's with 4 question marks, but hopefully not) :

```
SET @id = ?;

SELECT info = 'Posts', count(*) FROM posts WHERE topicid = @id
UNION ALL
SELECT info = 'Views', count(*) FROM topic_activity WHERE topicid = @id
UNION ALL
SELECT info = 'Likes', count(*) FROM topic_activity WHERE topicid = @id AND likes = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT info = 'DisLikes', count(*) FROM topic_activity WHERE topicid = @id AND likes = -1
```

But that returns 4 records where you'll then need to extract the data out by means of the `info` field. So, building on the idea of user3106988's answer to return just 1 record with all the info in different fields you could actually go for the likes & disklikes in as little effort as below. Should be quite fast.

```
SET @id = ?;

SELECT SUM(count_posts) as count_posts, 
       SUM(views) as views, 
       SUM(likes) as likes, 
       SUM(dislikes) as dislikes
FROM(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as count_posts, 
           0 as views, 
           0 as likes, 
           0 as dislikes 
      FROM posts 
     WHERE topicid = @id
UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 as count_posts, 
           COUNT(*) as views, 
           SUM(Case WHEN likes = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as likes, 
           SUM(Case WHEN likes = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as dislikes 
      FROM topic_activity 
     WHERE topicid = @id
) T;
```

Comment: Wow. Genius. Zeige Datensätze 0 - 0 ( 1 insgesamt, Die Abfrage dauerte 0.0021 Sekunden)

Comment: 3 Queries. Each of them would run in 0.0003s. This solution takes 0.0021. Is it still better than multiple single queries in this case?

Comment: Hard to tell; I'm surprised to learn that the combination of them takes that much longer. Which approach is best ... don't know; I guess it depends on how much overhead it is in your program to launch 3 queries and fetch the 3 values one by one; versus running just the 1 query but having all results immediately.

Comment: I just notice there is a bug in the last part of the query; the (CASE .. END)'s should be enclosed in a SUM(). I'll see if I can still edit my answer and correct it

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count_post, topic_activity
FROM(
    SELECT count(*) AS count_post, NULL AS topic_activity FROM posts WHERE topicid = ?
UNION
    SELECT NULL AS count_post, count(*) AS topic_activity FROM topic_activity WHERE topicic =?
) T
GROUP by count_post, topic_activity
```

let me know if it works

Comment: Sry. Works.. I messed it up with the ? placeholders. Thanks for this.

Comment: Actually, imho it does NOT work as intended. It seems to me user3106988 tried to return 1 record with two values but due to the `GROUP BY` actually retursn 1 record with data for one column and another record with data for the other record. Simply remove the last line and use SUM()'s around the fields in the `SELECT` part.